# React router v4 ending slash ambiguity

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-v4

I could't go to the `Add` page when I clicked the `Add` link in `Scoreboard`.

If I tried to add `exact` to the route of `/scoreBoard` in `App`, then I couldn't go back to `ScoreBoard` when I clicked `Back` in `Add` page because the url contains an ending slash `/scoreBoard/`.

Of course I can remove the slash when I put it to the `Link`. I am not sure is there any alternative to this?

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Link to='/scoreBoard'>ScoreBoard</Link>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/' render={() => <h1>Home</h1>}/>
          <Route path='/scoreBoard' component={ScoreBoard}/>
          <Route path='/scoreBoard/add' component={AddScorePanel}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
};

const ScoreBoard = ({match}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>ScoreBoard</h1>
      <Link to={`${match.url}/add`}>Add</Link>
    </div>
  );
};

const AddScorePanel = ({match}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add</h1>
      <Link to={`${match.url}/..`}>Back</Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Does using `exact path="/scoreBoard/"`solve the problem?

Comment: @lilezek Good suggestion. I think that can solve the problem and it is a clean solution. But then I always need to put an ending slash to the `to` for all the `Link`. Just curiosity, I still want to know how others solve this.